# R plotting linear SVM kernel does not plot a line

Tags: r, classification, svm, e1071

I am using `e1071` package in R to fit a linear kernel SVM and then to plot the separating hyperplane. The code I apply is taken from [here](http://uc-r.github.io/svm).

```
svmfit <- svm(y~., data = dat, kernel = "linear", scale = FALSE)
# Plot Results
plot(svmfit, dat)
```

The plot is as the following, and I don't know why the separation is not simply linear (but some zig-zag). Any thoughs?

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong, but it simply looks like a graphic thing. If you improve the quality of the plot, it is likely that you won't see the "zig-zag".

Comment: Ok, from ISLR book: `due to the way in which the plotting function is implemented in this library the decision boundary looks somewhat jagged in the plot.`